# Magento CE 1.9 collecting the LowStockDate value

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, stock, out-of-stock

I've made a quick script to collect out of stock products that are:

a) qty greater than 0
b) have been out of stock for 2 weeks.

This will then set the is_instock_value for products that match those conditions.

```
$time = time(); // get current time
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$lastTime = $time - 1209600; // 14 days ago
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    //->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

foreach ($products as $_product) {

    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
    $lowstockdate = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product->getLowStockDate());

        if ($stock->getQty() > 0 && $lowstockdate > $from){
            echo $_product->getSku()." = ";
            echo $stock->getQty()." = ";
            echo $_product->getName()." = ";
            echo $_product->getLowStockDate()."<br>";
            $stock->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
            $stock->save();
        }
}
```

The problem is i cant the getLowStockDate() to work. For some reason its not returning anything.

Comment: Following @Kajal Shah's answer i have added variables collecting the time and a calculation to work out the difference. I have updated my question with the progress so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work in the end it was down to several things but mainly i needed to join the product collection with the stock item table. Without this i was unable to check qty in particular.

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->joinField(
                'qty',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            );
```

It was also necessary to call multiple $stock variables as i was unable to return the LowStockDate value without this.

```
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($p); // necessary for getLowStockDate
```

and to set the item value to in stock (1) i had to load it again by ID

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($p->getId());
```

I'm sure there are more efficient ways but it gets the job done so i'm happy with this. Working code is below for anyone that may find this useful. Basically it will loop through all your products that are 1) out of stock 2) qty greater than 0 and 3) the low stock date is greater than the time set in $lastTime = $time - 1209600. Any products that are found will then be set to instock and saved.

```
<?php 
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require_once '/home/willowhill/public_html/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
umask(0);

echo "<h1>Set In Stock Script</h1><br>";

$time = time(); // get current time
$lastTime = $time - 1209600; // Minus 14 days for 2 weeks = 1209600 seconds
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime); // convert to date format

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection') // product collection note i had to join the stock item table to access various attributes
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->joinField(
                'qty',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            );
$c = 0;

foreach($products as $p){

    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($p); // necessary for getLowStockDate
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($p->getId());
    $pid = $p->getId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
    $productSKU = $product->getSku();

        if ($p->getQty() > 0 && $product->getIsInStock() < 1 && $stock->getLowStockDate() < $from ) {
            //&& $product->getIsInStock() < 1 && $stock->getLowStockDate() < $from
            echo $productSKU." = ";
            echo $p->getQty()." = ";
            echo $product->getIsInStock()." = ";
            echo $stock->getLowStockDate()." = ";
            echo $p->getName()." = ";
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
            $stockItem->save();

        }
}

echo($c . " product(s) updated.");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the date difference from date of low stock and current date.If this duration is more than 14 days then your code should be worked.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Kajal I have added some variables to collect the time and work out the difference. Please see updated question.